# chmod: changing permissions of ‘my_script.sh’: Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, bash, shell

when I'm trying to make shell script that error is shown ,what i must do ??

```
 [rehamadel@localhost bin]$ sudo vi my_script.sh
```

`[sudo] password for rehamadel:`

`[rehamadel@localhost bin]$ ls -l my_script.sh`

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 52 Jul 30 19:25 my_script.sh
[rehamadel@localhost bin]$ chmod u+x my_script.sh
chmod: changing permissions of ‘my_script.sh’: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Unless you need the script to run as `root`, change the *owner* and *group* to your owner and group, e.g. `sudo chown youruser:yourgoup my_script.sh`, then make sure it is executable, e.g. `chmod 0754 my_script.sh`. Then you can execute your script. (or simply call it with bash to begin with `bash my_script.sh` (or `su -c "bash my_script.sh"` if owned by `root``)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Resolving the operation not permitted error:

```
sudo chmod u+x my_script.sh
```

You created the file via:

```
sudo vi my_script.sh
# editing
```

This means, the owner and group of the file is root. You are not allowed to change files of it by default. You need to change permission (chmod does it) or change the owner:

```
sudo chown you:yourgroup my_script.sh
```

This should do it. Save the trouble, without creating the file via sudo.

Answer (score 9):

You've created file `my_script.sh` with the *root* user as the owner (because you used `sudo`), which is why you're not permitted to change the permissions as *yourself*.

Thus, use `sudo chmod u+x my_script.sh`, but note that that will make the file only executable for the *root* user.

To make the file executable by everyone, use `sudo chmod a+x my_script.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error because I uploaded the files via winscp and was trying to change permission on Linux window. 
I was able to change permissions via winscp.